# How to process/concatenate react-intl message with an EL expression?

Tags: reactjs, el, material-ui, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

This code works:

```
import { MessageResource } from 'react-intl'
.
.
.
<FlatButton label={`(${this.props.patCount})`}> {<MessageResource id="T_DUMMY_VALUE_KEY"/>} </FlatButton>
```

For ex: if `<MessageResource id="T_DUMMY_VALUE_KEY"/>` gives string **Patients**
and `${this.props.patCount}` gives **10** then the label will turn out to be:

> Patients (10)

But my requirement is to bring all the string processing together within label attribute something like this:

```
    import { MessageResource } from 'react-intl'
    .
    .
    .
    <FlatButton label={<MessageResource id="T_DUMMY_VALUE_KEY"/> + `(${this.props.patCount})`} />
```

This does not work and gives me output like this:

> [OBJECT OBJECT] (10)

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [link](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattedmessage) for more information.

> Message Formatting Fallbacks
>   The message formatting APIs go the extra mile to provide fallbacks for the common situations where formatting fails; at the very least a non-empty string should always be returned. Here's the message formatting fallback algorithm:
>
> Lookup and format the translated message at id, passed to .
>
> 1. Fallback to formatting the defaultMessage.
> 2. Fallback to translated message at id's source.
> 3. Fallback to defaultMessage source.
> 4. Fallback to the literal message id.

Lets say you have one message that has an id: message_one_id
And you want to concatenate the second message into it.

***Your Messages json file looks like below if you have one. Or I am doing the below example with defaultMessages.***

```
{
  message_one_id: "Unread ({loading})",
  loading: "Loading...",
}
```

You can use the following method:

```
<FormattedMessage id="message_one_id"
                  defaultMessage="Unread ({loading})"
                  values={{
                           loading: <FormattedMessage 
                                           id="loading"
                                           defaultMessage="Loading..."
                                    />
                         }}
/>
```

**This will output:**

`Unread (Loading...)`

### You can also use this to even dynamically print message:

```
class NotificationCount extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
                   notification: []
                 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const notifications = [
        {"id": "1", msg: "hello"},
        {"id": "2", msg: "world"}
      ];
    this.setState({notification: notifications});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FormattedMessage id="message_one_id"
                        defaultMessage="Unread ({loading})"
                        values={{
                           loading: `${this.state.notification.length}`
                         }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**This will output:**

`Unread (2)`